# Why Laser "Guns"?

Tags: science-fiction, weapons, lasers

We all love laser guns (which are usually plasma weaponry) but why guns? It's not like we need the long barrel for making it more accurate or the stock to control recoil. So why guns and why not something else?

Comment: Long barrel and stock are parts of rifles. Guns have handle to keep in hand and barrel to aim.

Comment: Are you asking for (1) justification of the gun shape of the fictional laser gun, or (2) if future handheld laser weapons would actually be gun shaped?

Comment: You need to elaborate more on the question. Pure rhetorical and open questions like this are "too broad". There are dozens of answers and we cannot know which one is a better fit for the question if it is too vague.

Comment: http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/sidearmenergy.php#id--Lasers--Design

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper ...or possibly OP is just asking why we use the word "gun" instead of "laser blaster" or some other word.  Who knows?  The question is vague and poorly defined.

Comment: Phasers are usually not shaped like recognizable guns, especially post-TOS, in the mainstream universe at least.

Comment: Closest thing irl looks like this: https://m.wickedlasers.com/arctic — nothing like a gun but reasonably muzzle-like. Just my two cents of real life.

Comment: It's a piece or a weapon, never a gun. Which part of this question doesn't belong on ELU? And what "something else" did you have in mind that would give cause to reinvent the +300yo ergonomics of handheld, ranged weapons?

Comment: Don't high power lasers (i.e. not laser pointers) use a rod-shaped gain medium, where the light comes out of one end? (well both ends, but one end has a fully reflective mirror that stops it leaving the gun)

Comment: What would you prefer in place of "gun"?

Comment: @AzorAhai I so hope (yet fear it's not so) that Picard's new series won't change that...

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY: Rifles are a type of gun.  So are pistols, shotguns, the cannon in figher jets and on naval ships.  The primary purpose of the barrel in a "gunpowder" gun is not to aim, it is to contain the force produced by the burning propellant so it accelerates the bullet.  (Interesting fact: you need different propellants for rifles & pistols.  Pistol powder must burn fast because of the short barrel.  Using pistol powder in a rifle can wreck it: http://bulletin.accurateshooter.com/2015/01/what-happens-when-you-load-pistol-powder-in-a-rifle-cartridge/

Comment: Because rayguns with a dish look stupid.

Answer (score 71):

## User Expectation and Skeumorphic Design

The floppy disk  is used (less so than five years ago, but used) as a save icon, even though outside of old industrial machines and nuclear missile silos, no one uses floppy disks. Your phone makes a shutter sound when you take a picture, despite not having a shutter. Electric cars are designed to look like gasoline vehicles in many ways that are utterly unnecessary, because it’s what people *expect*, and when something looks the way people expect, it makes them happy and comfortable and more likely to award your Laser Gun Company with the government contract for one million Pew Pew Guns. So your industrial designers make it look like a nice old fashioned projectile-throwing rifle, even if it doesn’t strictly need to.

Comment: I think you hit on the broad psychological phenomenon here. The "gun" is just a literary/theatrical icon for "weapon".

Comment: But electric cars do share most of the same requirements and limits as any other car, so of course they'll look similar. A hard disk doesn't have the same technical limits of a floppy, so the actual device looks completely different. Skeumorphic design isn't a successful solution in the physical world, and "next generation" devices which use it temporarily are always quickly replaced by designs which use the nature of the new device to do the job better.

Comment: "less so than five years ago" I have literally never seen another icon for save.

Comment: @jpmc26 in the UX world, there are ongoing debates about idioms (the save icon) vs metaphors (what the save icon once was) and attempts to phase out the former, but the details didn’t feel germane to the answer.

Comment: I'm suggesting that it's still ubiquitous. Any usages of another icon are rare. "less so" suggests that it's actually starting to decline, but I'm just not convinced that's the case.

Comment: On a side note, the shutter sounds prevent someone from sneaking in a photo. It became mandatory in Japan in the early 2000s to curb an upskirt epidemic, so it does serve a function still. The same logic could be applied to gun shapes, to make them recognisable and unable to be passed as something mundane.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'd say that auto-saving without any icon is causing decreased usage of the save symbol. So basically, it's usage is not declining because people don't recognize it (they do, perhaps not as a floppy disk (or, actually a diskette) but as the save icon) but just because there is less of a need for a save icon.

Comment: Speaking as someone who likes firepower and isn't terribly bright, I would probably buy the weapon that shaped like a pistol instead of a TV remote. Also, practically speaking, one of the points of carrying a weapon is other people knowing your carrying a weapon, meaning they are tools of intimidation. Having advanced weapons look like older, more primitive ones makes sense from a psychological perspective.

Comment: this is an awesome answer, but you've certainly already rep-capped today. will UV tomorrow if I remember :)

Comment: @AmiralPatate you're raising a very good point that makes this answer much more relevant.

Comment: @jpmc26 Other icons for save (as well as other file-related actions) were quite common until the late 1990s. See for example [this September 1996 review of Win32 C++ compilers](https://tarma.com/articles/1996sep.htm). Make sure to check out the full-size screenshots.

Comment: Do people actually look at for a "Save" icon?  Or do they expect to see the word "Save" and just ignore the funny picture next to it?

Comment: @jamesqf: Most toolbars don't have text, only icons.  Only with the popularity of "ribbons" instead of toolbars, has text become common (and still not on every function).  Consider the toolbar in this picture, where open and save are obvious from the symmetry (no "diskette" is used): https://www.file-extensions.org/imgs/app-picture/1404/lotus-word-pro.png

Comment: @Ben Voigt: We must be using different definitions of the word "obvious" :-)  While I've never used Lotus, I would expect to find "Save" listed under "File".  Just as this browser has "Save page as", Acrobat reader has "Save a copy", and I think a plane "Save" if  it's a editable file...

Comment: @jamesqf: The menus are there also, and in fact the status bar was used for mouseover text to explain toolbar buttons.  But both of those require interactions, you can't find them by just looking at a static screen.  And because you were talking about the "funny picture", I assumed you meant the toolbar.  Icons in menus aren't very common.

Comment: @Graham, Re "*But electric cars do share most of the same requirements and limits as any other car*", Electric cars aren't the best example, but it works. Electric cars place their batteries along the bottom, which makes them very stable cars, but it also makes them taller. And that makes them look weird. Why? Because it's different. I doubt we'd find them weird if all cars were like that. They're finally starting to come out with electric cars that look great (e.g. Chev Volt), and guess what... They are indistinguishable from gas cars.

Comment: @ikegami They only become taller if you place the batteries under the floorpan. There are plenty of other places to put them though, in the same way as a gas tank doesn't have to go under the floorpan. The height isn't anything special anyway - check any small SUV. What was different about early electric cars was the "futuristic" design, which was deliberately copying sci-fi film cars in the same way as 1950s styling. Most of it served no practical purpose.

Comment: Most of the design details on a gas car are about practicalities. Aerodynamics don't change when you go electric. People don't change shape, so the cabin is the same. You still need somewhere to put luggage. You still need all the same lights. And whilst the engine compartment may not be needed, the crumple zone from that space certainly is. If you change that, you don't just stop the car looking good, you make it less effective as a car. And that's why earlier electric cars sucked, not just because they looked strange.

Answer (score 51):

It's an interesting question because our current laser guns look more like giant flat panels that fire invisible beams of heat at airplanes and torpedoes.

But those are aimed by computers.  People need to use sights to aim.  A longer barrel gives a more accurate sight and better control of the gun.  It also allows the weapon to function like a bat in close fighting and could hold other attachments like grenade launchers or backup conventional rifles for when laser just won't work (like the Chinese mirror armor they developed in response to USA laser weapons).

Comment: It's not about the size of your rail attachment system, it's how you use it!

Comment: The problem is that future warfare with advanced weapons maybe totally computer operated, rather than having stormtroopers running around with blasters.

Comment: Longer barrels in guns, especially rifles, are not for sighting but helping maintain a truer trajectory.

Comment: @bruglesco it serves many purposes. Maintaining trajectory and increasing initial velocity are important ones, but distance for sights also have some role.

Comment: @Mołot maybe at some point but laser pointers and scopes are far more effective and growing more and more common. (I still upvoted btw)

Comment: I guess adding a laser pointer on a laser gun in not such a bad idea.

Comment: @bruglesco Laser pointers and scopes needs non-negligible muzzle length to be mounted on anyway, otherwise you could have a laser weapon that's hardly bigger than a handle alone. O course, on laser weapons there is no point for having aiming device that doesn't require power, because if you do not have power you are not shooting anyway...

Comment: @AzirisMorora I guess really the gun itself could fire a low power version to function as the targeting before it fires the lethal version.

Comment: @TrevorD Depends on what sooting looks like. Shooting a ray that you can track would help aiming. 
Shooting a small dot at light speed wouldn't be much help.

Comment: I am picturing a light only visible through special glasses or goggles, so invisible to anyone not equipped to see them.

Comment: @TrevorD This is called laser designation, already used with AN-PEQ attachments and NV google :)

Comment: @bruglesco A longer barrel produces a higher velocity and therefore a flatter ballistic trajectory. It also increases the sight radius, but this is only relevant with traditional "iron" sights. The idea that a longer barrel makes the bullet fly straighter is fuddlore.

Comment: @TKK  "flatter ballistic trajectory" = straighter, in layman terms.

Comment: @Mołot Given how many firearm enthusiasts misunderstand external ballistics, I don't think the average person has any concept of it at all. Anyway, the belief that longer barrels are inherently more accurate is both widespread and wrong.

Comment: Don't forget that a laser's output energy is governed in part by the number of atoms that can be fluoresced in resonance, which, for a given width/diameter chamber, is a function of its length.

Comment: @bruglesco Only past a certain point.  At one extreme you can imagine a laser weapon shaped kind of like a GoPro (so a fairly flat, rectangular box).  Aiming such a device so that the laser it emits strikes the intended target in the intended location under combat conditions and while your target is likely moving around to avoid being hit is going to be difficult (if not near impossible) even at close and medium range.  If you give it a barrel and make it at least pistol shaped, it's much quicker and easier for a person to intuitively and semi-accurately point it at nearby targets.

Comment: Ergonomics, +1. I have a ~3" group with pistols at a measly ten feet. Or a ~3" group at 100 *yards* with a rifle...

Comment: @Mazura: Exactly. A rifle's form factor also lends itself to be a more stable platform for firing. Long range shooters will still want something long enough to be propped up by terrain/structures/stands without interfering with their hands/arms. Additionally, more volume could mean more hardware for either more powerful lasers or more shots before emptying, much like existing rifles/pistols make tradeoffs for.

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at the wikipedia article on [lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser).

> A laser consists of a gain medium, a mechanism to energize it, and something to provide optical feedback.[8] The gain medium is a material with properties that allow it to amplify light by way of stimulated emission. Light of a specific wavelength that passes through the gain medium is amplified (increases in power).

The accompanying diagram shows that the gain medium is a long tube. The longer the gain medium is, the more the laser is amplified.

Furthermore, one can have a laser version of [choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(firearms)) (change the spread of the beam) by having a series of adjustable lenses, and a long barrel facilitates that.

Comment: +1 Stavatti SF-1 Gasdynamic laser rifle (the only realistic design so far AFAIK) has 20in (50cm) chamber alone. The power source is just as big, and the significant recoil makes stacking those the obvious option.

Comment: @Agent_L you mention recoil, and while laser weapons do have recoil, unless you are trying to blow a planet up, I don't think the recoil would be "significant". Am I missing something?

Comment: The gain depends on the volume, but the length (aspect ratio) of the resonator determines the divergence and that places lower limit on how well the beam can be focused.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner In this case, the recoil comes from gas being rushed into the chamber at Mach 6 to power the lasing action (the gasdynamic part). The recoil is forward, opposite of guns. I wholeheartedly recommend reading about SF-1 and TIS-1 whitepaper, because that's fiction transitioning into science in front of us.

Answer (score 13):

Cooling system

Longer, mean more cooling, mean more heat can be dissipated, mean more powerful laser / you can use it for a longer period of time

That might be unrealistic but in a sci-fi world, why not (imagine a new metal/cooling technology to miniaturize everything)

Comment: That kind of works, unless you consider that the laser weapon still files straight without a barrel, and there is no need to dissipate heat from a barrel that doesn't exist. So it's kind of a solution to a problem that only exists because of your solution. Also longer would only usefully dissipate heat if the source of the heat was at the tip of the barrel, insulating the user from heat. So yeah longer dissipates heat, but did we need it dissipated from the barrel? I would expect the battery would be the heat problem.

Comment: @TrevorD Industrial lasers need quite a bit of active cooling (and those aren't powerful enough to be useful small arms!). For passive cooling, you need a lot of surface area. It's pretty easy to spread the heat around the heatsink, the throughput limit is on the radiators.

Comment: @Luaan Can you confirm if its the laser creating the heat, or the power source powering the laser?

Comment: A laser has to create heat, by physics a laser emitter has to be hotter than it intends to make the target.

Comment: @John But the laser itself doesn't deliver much of that heat to the barrel as it passes through, since the laser doesn't touch the barrel.  But the barrel *can* be connected to the power supply, so it will conduct heat away from that.  It's a cooling coil that you can mount a sight on.

Comment: Put the battery in the shoulder stock, and the cooling in the barrel. I'm not trying to be realistic; in reality lasers aren't in a gun form factor. But as the question assume that we have laser shaped like guns, the question is why is that. So I try to give an answer to that question.

Comment: @Ray why would the barrel be a "barrel", it could just be the emitter, its optics and the housing, it is the emitter itself that generates the most heat so you want it directly connected to a a mass that can act as both a heat sink and a cooling system.

Comment: @TrevorD With the lasers we have, the power supply is *far* more efficient than the laser itself. There's losses to the lasing medium, losses to the mirrors, and for microchip lasers, of course the chip gets quite hot (there the heating issue for dangerous laser might be almost insurmountable). In any case, even the heat from the power source needs to be dissipated - and if you use passive cooling, that means lots of radiators. The point is, the barrel is going to be there anyway, and "rifle" (or carabine/SMG) ergonomics are vastly superior to one-handed weapons; gun-shape is smart.

Comment: @John Just because it's called a barrel doesn't mean it is a barrel. It has pretty much the same function, and there's no reason to change the name, really. The same way we still distinguish between pistols and rifles, even though both pistols and rifles have rifling. "Rifle" no longer means what it used to mean when first rifles appeared. Pistol itself used to be a hand cannon (two-handed, of course), with the only similarity to modern pistols being you use an explosive to propel a projectile out of the barrel. Why not call a laser rifle a rifle, and laser pistol a pistol?

Comment: @Luaan I meant Ray describes the barrel as something that only wraps around the beam, there is no reason for it to be built this way, the barrel should be the part that actually houses the emitter and optics. meaning direct heating by contact with said pieces, just like in normal lasers.

Comment: @John I misread your first comment. I thought you said that the laser *beam* must be hotter than it intends to make the target, rather than the emitter.

Answer (score 6):

To aim a weapon accurately, a long barrel is helpful. You also want to have some heft to dampen jitter (Photographers know that a light camera is harder to hold steady).

As well, you need some place to put all of the tech, even if you don't need a long lasing cavity you'll find some use for the volume. A short but thick device would be much less practical, for aiming as well as for carrying.

Of course the validity of all of these reasons depends entirely on the author's whim in a scifi setting. You coud have a short, giro stabilized hand gun with computer assisted aiming and nano components if you so please, but who wants to ruin a good trope?

Comment: Note that your aiming statement assumes "iron sights". Optical sights, such as the current ACOG, can do the job in a much shorter length.

Comment: hm, maybe optical sights arent such a good idea when your opponents point lasers at you?

Comment: Well, only for a very particular set of enemy lasers and powers. It would be better only if the optical gain of the optical sight brought enemy emissions over damage thresholds, and most low-power sights don't have all that much gain. Actually, it's perfectly possible to include band-reject filters in optical sights which would make them much safer than using iron sights and Mark I (unprotected) eyeballs.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: A rifle-like form factor would still help with accuracy in that you have more/cleaner options for resting the firearm on terrain/structures/stands. I'd imagine long-ranger shooters would still prefer something larger than a pistol or TV remote in order to accurately hit targets from afar.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast ACOG rifles still have iron sights as backup; optical sights can "easily" be thrown out of alignment, and then all you have is an oversized hip-fired SMG :) But anyway, even with optic sights, the ergonomics of the weapon don't really change - you still want something comfortably held in both hands, with one side braced against your shoulder. A HUD (like the  Star Wars Stormtroopers have) could make hip-fired weapons reasonably accurate, but that's again something you want a backup for.

Comment: Jitter and sights is kind of silly on a futuristic weapon. Why not let a computer aim it and use servos to compensate for any jitter.

Comment: @ZanLynx - Unless you're on one-way-trip vacation to collect the intact nervous systems of the finest human specimens, why are you even there yourself?

Answer (score 4):

Some considerations from Atomic Rockets (They have a gorgeous article about side-arms on hard Sci-Fi):

A portable laser weapon can't realisticly exist, since we have a major problem on [portability of batteries](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/sidearmenergy.php#id--Lasers--Power_Supply) and to save energy they would need focusing lens what can drive their form to be like a old [Super 8 camoder](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/sidearmenergy.php#id--Lasers--Laser_Muzzle) due lens size.

Aiming can be done by a [periscope](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/sidearmenergy.php#id--Lasers--Targeting), as in Star Trek, as energy weapons don't have trajectory deformations, like projectiles, reducing the need for a barrel.

Comment: You're not using enough imagination (or reading enough Project Rho :P). A lot of older sci-fi used laser (and other "energy") weapons with battery backpacks. We already have batteries with far higher energy density than you would need for that. Is that a good idea? Of course not, but then again, propelling a deadly projectile with a small explosive isn't exactly sane either :D People do all sorts of ludicrous stuff with severe drawbacks to fight other people. If your magazine is hit with a laser weapon, is it going to go off? Is that much different than the danger posed by laser charges?

Comment: Older Sci-Fi had different standards. We don't have any battery close enough energy density and stability to be of practical use, even on a backpack form factor. Of course, we can use a handwavium battery, and use large lens to make this transgression less flagrant.

Comment: There are two things IMO for us to advance to the next age: near free energy (and more importantly for considerations such as this question) the ability to store, transport, and quickly discharge it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is just for readers/viewers to be able to recognize in a fraction of a second that the character is holding a weapon that can hit at a distance.

To justify this would be so that military personnel doesn't need to adapt to a new way of fighting and can be even more efficient than before without the required formation time. 
Then you still need batteries, plasma ammunition, electronics to handle the energy release, attachments and so on that make is as big as a classic gun.

Comment: Not just the viewers - the first season or so of *Star Trek: the Next Generation* used less gun-like phasers (affectionately known as "dustbusters" for their shape) that had to be phased out, no pun intended, because the *actors* couldn't reliably point them at their targets.

Comment: The TNG phasers were my first thought when reading this. They weren't gun-like, and they failed. From the perspective of getting an audience to accept a fictional element, it's less of a jump to use something they recognize. Answers trying to justify the rifle shape of "laser guns" are all based on our current tech/cultural framework, anyways. Which is why it's important to clarify the question - are we asking "why do most fictional universes portray them this way?" or are we asking "what might they actually be like in a "realistic" future fictional universe?"

Comment: @Cadence As a counterpoint, the hand weapons from Blake's 7 looked nothing like conventional guns, - see image here: https://www.therpf.com/forums/threads/blakes-7-prop-replicas.41273/ but they sure looked easy enough to use in the show.  One of the unintentionally unanswered questions from that show was any hint as to the nature of the former owners of the ship that Blake and his allies started using.  Those weapons suggest that they might not have been completely anthropomorphic.

Comment: I'm just picturing Zat guns now.

Comment: @dwizum I've never imagined the ST hand phaser as a primary weapon - it's all about the concealment. The Federation likes to appear peaceful and straightforward, and when their operative is caught, the phaser doesn't look like a weapon (we've even seen that on the show); it's designed not to look like a weapon. It's more like the single-shot concealed guns that used to be pretty popular for ladies, or something like a gun in your walking stick - not accurate at all, just something inconspicuous you can easily carry for emergencies. It also doubles as a tool, somewhat akin to a survival knife.

Answer (score 2):

Your "long barrel" comment implies a rifle configuration as opposed to a pistol configuration.

For a given level of technology a rifle has more space for "stuff" than a pistol.

### What sort of stuff?

- Power/energy: it can fire more times before it runs out of juice. It can also pack a greater punch for armour piercing.
- Targeting: The rifle form factor allows invisible light sensors to read the eyes of the shooter and automatically place the laser on target. It also allows dynamic aiming adjustment to keep the shot on target long enough to be effective. I always thought Predator shoulder mounts have no way of targeting unless linked to a visor.
- Crowd suppression: either multi-shot (machine gun-like but each shot targeted) or wide beam (close up shotgun-like scattershot).
- Robust/Hardened design: smaller form factors are more prone to failure of delicate parts. A laser that can't shoot is just a stick.
- Heuristics/Learning curve. It's pretty obvious which end to point towards enemy and a trigger to activate. If it looked like a Dyson Airblade (or a makeup mirror, or a bow & arrow) it's not so obvious.

### Alternate form factors

I believe we are in the last generation of personal war-fighting. Drones and automatons are the future.

So an adventuring rascal of the future is more likely to have a weapon drone in close proximity or close response time.

- Yondu Udonta in Guardians of the Galaxy has his Yaka Arrow.
- Han Solo should have wasted Greedo (first!) with a small remote sitting on the booth. Of course that would change the cowboy elements of the space opera.

Close protection drones would probably be big enough to shield behind while they lay fire upon aggressors. So I'm guessing the size of a riot shield.

If personal anti-gravity doesn't exist in your world then the drone has wheels and/or legs.

Another approach: the Close Protection Drone is actually made up of nano-robots hiding as clothing and cover exposed body parts quickly. Return fire is handled by specialised nano-bots that are part of the outfit and therefore have no specific form. Laser fire shoots out of the body.

Answer (score 2):

1. The laser source is a long tube. The beam bounces back and forth in it and is amplified by the excited medium inside. The thinner and longer the tube is, the better collimated the beam is. That means it does not spread as much and therefore remains effective at longer distance.
2. The long barrel also makes aiming more accurate.
3. The stock is not needed to absorb recoil, but the additional fixed point it provides improves how steady you can hold it to get good aim.

Comment: Also, the stock can house the heavier bits of the rifle (like the power supply) - this again makes it much easier to hold and aim the weapon, regardless of recoil. You want a heavy point near your body (which doesn't move much), and a relatively light end (that makes it easy to change the weapon's orientation).

Comment: Point 1 is true for some lasers, but not semiconductor or fiber based lasers. Laser diodes are simply chips, and fiber lasers/amplifiers have the fiber rolled into a spool.

Comment: @user71659, the aspect ratio of semiconductor and fiber lasers still determines their divergence. They are just very small generally in the first case, or allow not having the resonator straight in the second. Since the gain is limited by volume, you need something bigger for a gun anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A real futuristic personal laser weapon would probably sit on someones shoulder and the aim point would track whatever the user was looking at. It would not look like a gun at all.

Comment: Why would it? You've proposed an alternative, but you don't really discuss *why* that alternative would be the most likely. Can you [Edit] to elaborate on the reasoning behind your answer?

Comment: Watched _Predator_ recently have we.

Comment: this answers exactly the opposite question to the one posed.

Comment: Why? Because there's nothing better than accelerating an actual mass at your enemy with e.g. a plasmacaster. Also, shoutout to *Blue Thunder*. "A real futuristic personal ' 'laser beam' ' weapon would probably" ... shoot bolts of plasma. And actually it would finally be back to looking like a (deck) 'gun' instead of a firearm.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your question is when asking about an imaginary weapon that does not yet exist, so any answer would depend on which particular weapon you're referring to.

But not all laser type weapons are shaped like a gun, some are shaped more like a TV remote control than a gun. (more photos [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/25318/19183) )

[image]

Though even the federation uses a [more traditional long barreled rifle-like shape](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Type_3_phaser?file=Phaser_rifle.jpg) for larger guns, and since it's made up technology there can be lots of reasons including cooling, a longer laser/phaser chamber for more power, etc

Comment: Luckily these must have about a 30 degree error correction, given some of the angles we've seen energy come out of them. It's going to need a selfie cam to know what you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent reason given by Daniel B, there are other considerations with the look, expectations and usability issues. Guns, like knifes or spears, have two ends, a good one and a bad one. If your laser gun looks like the Star Trek TNG class 1 phaser:
[image]
then you not only risk holding it the wrong way (darn it, which way to enemy?), but also it isn't clear to enemies what you are holding. What's that, a garage opener? A medical scanner?

For a gun, as famously pointed out by Douglas Adams, it is important to make sure that you *know* when you are at the wrong end of it. With a traditional gun design, there is no doubt. Bullets come out... here.

Makes me think of a fun detail I saw in "Edge of Tomorrow". A thing that looked like what I believe is called a "claymore" mine with "This side to enemy" written on one of its otherwise identically looking sides. I don't know whether these have that text written on them in reality, but I wouldn't be surprised! The design sucks ass.

Now that we come to design, why does a pistol look like a pistol, and why do little boys who play cowboy point out their index finger? Well, guess why. Because that's exactly what the design of a pistol imitates, and it is exactly what we are innately able to do without training. You can just point your finger at something, and your finger will point to it 99% good. There's no doubt about what pointing the barrel towards something in the same manner will do either.

There would be much "better" designs for pistols that transmit recoil more favorably. But they *don't* let you point your imaginary index finger intuitively.

Comment: FRONT TOWARD ENEMY. Otherwise it's *your* ass.